# Highslide sometimes is not able to return its DIV, causing the view to be empty

Tags: highcharts, highslide

I have noticed that at random, when I click to open a view (I open highcharts inside HS), I get a blank view.

Checking the data, and everything is fine, but for some reason, the view is empty.
I did a bit of debugging and I found that the issue is where I pass the renderTo to the chart:

```
chartOptions.chart.renderTo= $('.highslide-body')[IDchart];
```

while debugging, sometimes the renderTo is undefined; so I am trying to troubleshoot this and figure out what is actually wrong.

the IDChart is always supplied; I have 10 charts; so in the click event of the chart I pass the chart id

```
IDchart=this.container.parentElement.getAttribute("data-highcharts-chart");
```

So from what I understand; if there are 10 charts on a page, and I click on the second, the highslide-body div has to be 2; 3 if I click on the 3rd chart and so on.

I am using this fiddle as guideline about how to open a HC in HS: jsfiddle.net/newbiez/AeFp3/

Altho this uses just one chart.

Has anyone ever experienced such issue with HS not rendering the content?

Comment: Have you posted this question in the regular Highcharts support forum? http://forum.highcharts.com/highcharts-usage/

Comment: We need a demo which introudce your issue, becuase which you attached, works properly.

Comment: @MisterNeutron: no, I didn't post it there yet, since I want to find out if is just me misusing, before post on their site. Sebastian: I will try to isolate the portion of the code and make it as simple fiddle; most of my work is done on a big file and I use fiddles just to get the concept of how things works, so I can implement them in my solution.