# Open multiple Highcharts charts in Highslide

Tags: highcharts, highslide

I tried in 3 different ways to achieve this; my solution is utterly unstable and finicky; so I guess I have as only option to ask how you did it.

I have multiple charts rendering on a web page; I want to click on each of them and open a full screen version of the chart, changing the settings.

I started with this fiddle; but I can do it only with one chart: 
jsfiddle.net/newbiez/AeFp3/

When I load the page, I create multiple chart in a loop, after I process data and assign it to each chart in loops too. I tried to use the approach of the fiddle, for multiple charts, but that means call the function that build the chart X times (X is the number of charts). Probably the solution is very simple, but since I am dealing with it for so long, I can't see it.

Any help would be appreciated; tried in various ways, and now I am short of ideas.

Comment: Have you posted this question in the regular Highcharts support forum? http://forum.highcharts.com/highcharts-usage/

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25238430/highslide-sometimes-is-not-able-to-return-its-div-causing-the-view-to-be-empty

Comment: Not yet, MisterNeutron; I will. @SebastianBochan: why is this a dupe? I am asking for a generic pseuddocode solution here, while in the other post I am reporting an issue encountered on the implementation of HS.